Opening an Excel File with Python
I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days now, and I cannot seem to get it. I simply need to open an existing Excel file, then I'll do some stuff with it, but I cannot seem to get the Excel file to open.
Here's what I've tried most recently:
import pyautogui
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pathlib
from pathlib import Path

wb_folder = Path("C:/Users/reber/Gaming/Rise of Castles/Member_Details/")

#md_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\reber\Gaming\Rise of Castles\Member_Details\Member_Details.xlsx')
#md_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\Users\reber\Gaming\Rise of Castles\Member_Details\Member_Details.xlsx')
#md_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\reber\Gaming\Rise of Castles\Member_Details\Member_Details.xlsx')
#md_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"C:\Users\reber\Gaming\Rise of Castles\Member_Details\Member_Details.xlsx")
md_wb = wb_folder / "Member_Details.xlsx"

f = open(md_wb)

p = pathlib.Path(__file__)
print (p)

Ultimately, I want to open the Excel file (to me, that means opening the workbook in the Excel application), perform actions in another application (clicking on specific parts of the screen) and then write back to Excel (essentially pasting what the aforementioned "clicking" captured).

have you tried with pandas.read_excel?

I have not tried panda's excel utilities yet.  I may have to if I can't get this to work.  Also, I wasn't getting an error.  The code seemed to run, just no actual result.

try this:
 for file_path in Path.cwd().glob("*Member_Details.xlsx"):
    new_path = Path("archive") / file_path.name
    print(new_path)


By what means are you determining the file didn't open, you just keep saying the file didn't open? What does your Excel file contain, just a few rows with data or complex Excel functions or is it quite large? Have you tried another Excel workbook. Have you tried copying the workbook to the same directory as the Python file to eliminate path issues if you believe that's a factor.

I'm determining the file didn't open by looking at Excel and seeing no files having been opened.  Right now, the workbook contains 1 worksheet with only a header row.  Yes, I've tried it with another workbook and with the file in my virtual environment.

"...by looking at Excel" , what does that mean? When using Openpyxl, Excel has nothing to do with the execution. Openpyxl uses OOXML to edit the XLSX file, the Excel App is not used and does not need to be installed.

@Rodger, I believe that the reason that this question was closed as a duplicate, was that you didn't make clear whether you wanted to use the open file in python and manipulate it using python or not. The answers below, rightly or wrongly, assumed that you wanted to open file in python and manipulate it using python. If this is true, then it is not a duplicate and should not be closed. Feel free to edit your question to make it clear, flag it for "moderator attention" and explain that it isn't a duplicate because your question is different.

@moken the information I've seen online certainly makes it appear that the application is being launched.

@CharlesKnell thank you.  Yes, there was more to the ask, but the first time I tried posting on this site, my question was closed because it was too detailed; so I tried to dial this one back.  I did edit the question, so hopefully it gets reopened.

@rodger, if you mean the application Excel then absolutely not. Excel or MS office apps and libs are not used in any way by Openpyxl. This module can be used with Linux because Excel is not a requirement.

re:"I want to open the Excel file (to me, that means opening the workbook in the Excel application)". In that case, your question is a duplicate. See the 3rd answer using "os.startfile" of the question linked to at the very top of this page. I don't know why you wouldn't want to use openpyxl to do your editing, but that is your decision.

If you wish to use the Excel Application to edit an XLSX file with Python then you need to use either Xlwings or Win32com. Other modules like Xlsxwriter and Pandas (which uses Openpyxl when opening a file) do not use Excel in any way. The choice of module will depend on specifically what your end requirement is. Openpyxl is popular because it doesn't use Excel. As mentioned it can run on pretty much any platform that can run Python as there is no dependency and given it is essentially a XLSX (XML) file editor it has lower recourse requirement, not needing to open a bloated MS application.

However Openpyxl is not always the best option, it does not work well or at all with some Excel features. Also the OOXML interface documentation is not great and some parts can be difficult to understand and implement. Xlsxwriter probably has more function but will only create new Excel workbooks. Xlwings is like VBA for Excel using Python but does mean every time you run it an Excel instance must be startaed.

@moken thank you VERY much!  Those last 2 comments help me better understand some capabilities and restrictions I hadn't picked up in reviewing the web.  All in, I will be doing a lot of copying from an app and pasting to Excel and vice versa.

@CharlesKnell regarding your question of, "I don't know why you wouldn't want to use openpyxl to do your editing, but that is your decision."; to be honest, it's probably a lack of knowledge issue on my part.  Perhaps I just haven't found good material to review, but what I've seen implies that you have to update Excel, save Excel, update Excel, save Excel, etc.  I plan to make hundreds, if not thousands of updates.

@Rodger, The index used when updating a cell can be computed, as in " sheet[cell_col+cell_row].value = 'E' ". You can make all your updates programmatically  and then save your workbook just once. Refer to my answer below.

Thank you!  I'm looking into this more now that my day job is done for the day

from pathlib import Path

import openpyxl

file_path = Path("/Users/naren.d/Downloads/sample_data.xlsx")

if not file_path.is_file():
    print(f"Error: The file '{file_path}' does not exist.")
else:
    print(f"The file '{file_path}' exists. Attempting to load...")

    try:
        md_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
        print(f"The file '{file_path} opened successfully")

        sheet = md_wb.active
        print("Worksheet title:", sheet.title)

        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=5, values_only=True):
            print(row)

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"The file '{file_path}' does not exist")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred {e}")

Output:
The file '/Users/naren.d/Downloads/sample_data.xlsx' exists. Attempting to load...
The file '/Users/naren.d/Downloads/sample_data.xlsx opened successfully
Worksheet title: Sheet1
('Name', 'Age', 'Department', 'Salary')
('John', 28, 'Sales', 50000)
('Alice', 24, 'HR', 55000)
('Bob', 35, 'Engineering', 70000)
('Diana', 22, 'Marketing', 48000)

Hi just an update It works when i tried this on mac.
for path issues you can refer

How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?

Handling file and directory Paths



I tried this, but the result was a message saying the workbook opened, but it didn't.  I think it's the pathing.  Here's what I tried:
file_path = Path("C:/Users/reber/Gaming/Rise of Castles/Member_Details/Member_Details.xlsx")
#file_path = Path('C:/Users/reber/Gaming/Rise of Castles/Member_Details/Member_Details.xlsx')

print(f"Resolved path: {file_path.resolve()}")
Could you check the path using the above statement
except openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException:         print(f"Error: The file '{file_path}' is not a valid Excel file.")     except Exception as e:         print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
further ways to debug the exception

Here is my demo.xlsx workbook:

Some demo code that accounts for a mistake in the path or the file is already open. It also shows how to edit cell B2 and save the file:
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path

wb_folder = Path(r"C:\Users\charl\PYTHON\stackoverflow_questions_2")
md_wb = wb_folder / "demo.xlsx"
print(f"File to open: {md_wb}")
workbook = None

try:
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(md_wb)
    sheet = workbook.active
    cell_col = 'B'
    cell_row = '2'
    print(f"current value: {sheet[cell_col+cell_row].value}")
    sheet[cell_col+cell_row].value = 'E'
    print(f"new value: {sheet[cell_col+cell_row].value}")
    workbook.save(md_wb)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File was not found: {md_wb}")

except PermissionError:
    print("Permission Error, file may already be open")

finally:
    workbook.close()


I tried this and nothing happened.  No error and the file didn't open.  I used this path:
wb_folder = Path(r"C:/Users/reber/Gaming/Rise of Castles/Member_Details")

Try a print statement to verify that md_wb is correct.

This resulted in
C:\Users\reber\Gaming\Rise of Castles\Member_Details\Member_Details.xlsx

Paste that string into your browser address bar and see if the file opens or downloads. It the string is wrong, the file won't open or download. If you use chrome, it will open.

Note: When you run the code, make sure that the file isn’t open using excel, the browser, or any other software.

I've updated my answer to account for a mistake in the md_wb or an already open file.

I've updated my answer to show you how to edit cell B2 using only python. I know it doesn't answer your question.
